# Как удалить в Excel все между двумя словами?

Tags: excel

Как удалить в Excel все между двумя словами?
Например, чтобы из значения "у лукоморья дуб зеленый, златая цепь на дубе том" убралось все между словами "лукоморья" и "дубе", т.е. "у лукоморья дубе том"

Comment: Решение зависит от условий задачи. Для показанного примера - простейшие формулы. Но, похоже, нужно что-то сложнее. Покажите пример таблицы с HTML-кодом и несколько вариантов нужных результатов. На VBA (макросы) нет аллергии?

Answer (score 0):

используй функции левсим(), правсим(), поиск() и длстр() для нарезки фразы, поиска слов и расчета длины фразы/слов. Твой пример решается кодом ниже (A2 - это ячейка с первоначальной фразой):

```
=ЛЕВСИМВ(A2;ПОИСК("лукоморья";A2;1)+ДЛСТР("лукоморья"))&ПРАВСИМВ(A2;ДЛСТР(A2)-ПОИСК("дубе";A2;1)+1)
```

Comment: Попробовал, все отлично работает с тестовой фразой, но не работает, когда я HTML код пытаюсь обрезать, место фразы

Comment: Посмотрите на повторяющиеся фразы. ПОИСК() ищет с указанного стартового значения. В пример указан 1 так, как все фразы уникальный.

Comment: @RowReverse, c HTML это работать ни когда не будет, это формат и у него есть правила. Для этого есть парсеры. Если это так важно, то стоит поправить вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Наверное это не совсем честный ответ, т.к. для решения использовался google spreadsheet.
Но там, пожалуй, самый простой способ подтянуть регулярки.
[image: REGEXEXTRACT example]

Подтягиваем первые 2 слова и 2 последних вместе с пробелами

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A36; "^(([^\s]+\s){2}).*((\s[^\s]+){2})$")
```

Колонка `A` и `C` всегда будет содержать требуемое значение, не зависимо от содержания строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ЗАМЕНИТЬ(A1;НАЙТИ("у лукоморья";A1)+12;99;"дубе том")
```

Здесь 99 - не меньше длины текста.

Логика. Находим начало удаляемого фрагмента, заменяем весь текст справа на нужное окончание.